# Server overloading due to mysql and tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, tomcat

I have a system where I have multiple sensors and I need to collect data from each sensor every minute. I am using

```
final Runnable collector = new Runnable(){public void run() {{...}};

scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(collector, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

to initiate the process every minute and starts an individual thread for each sensor. Each thread opens a mysql connection and gets details of the sensor from database, opens a socket to collect data and stores data into the database and closes socket and db connection. (I make sure all the connections are closed)
Now there are other applications which I use to generate alerts and reports from that data.

Now as the number of sensors are increasing the server starts to get overload and the applications are getting slow.

I need some expert advice, how to optimise my system and what is the best way to implement these type of systems. Should I use only one application to (collect data + generate alarm + generate reports, generate chart images + etc).

Thanks in advance.

Here is the basic code for data collector application

```
public class OnlineSampling
{
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    public void startProcess(int start)
    {
        try
        {
            final Runnable collector = new Runnable()
            {
                @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                public void run()
                {
                    DataBase db = new DataBase();
                    db.connect("localhost");
                    try
                    {
                        ArrayList instruments = new ArrayList();
                        //Check if the database is connected
                        if(db.isConnected())
                        {
                            String query="SELECT instrumentID,type,ip,port,userID FROM onlinesampling WHERE status = 'free'";
                            instruments = db.getData(query,5);
                            for(int i=0;i<instruments.size();i++)
                            {
                                ...

                                OnlineSamplingThread comThread = new OnlineSamplingThread(userID,id,type,ip,port,gps,unitID,parameterID,timeZone,units,parameters,scaleFactors,offsets,storageInterval);
                                comThread.start();
                                //This onlineSamplingThread opens the socket and collects the data and does few more things
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        //Disconnect from the database
                        db.disconnect();
                    }
                }
            };
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(collector, 0, 60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

UPDATED:

How many sensors do you have? We have around 400 sensors (increasing).
How long is data-gathering session with each sensor?

Each sensor has a small webserver with a sim card in it wo connect to the internet. It depends on the 3G network, in normal conditions it does not take more than 3.5 seconds.

Are you closing the network connections properly after you're done with a single sensor? I make sure I close the socket everytime, I have also set the timeout duration for each socket which is 3.5 seconds.

What OS are you using to collect sensor data? We have our own protocol to communicate with the sensors using socket programming.

Is it configured as a server or a desktop?  Each sensor is a server.

Comment: Try not to open different connection for each sensor, use existing ones. Also, some code would help.

Comment: Collecting data from hundreds of sensors should not pose a performance problem if done correctly but to answer your question, more information is needed: How many sensors do you have? How long is a data-gathering session with each sensor? Are you closing the network connections properly after you're done with a single sensor? What OS are you using to collect sensor data and is it configured as a server or a desktop? Are you writing sensor data to your DB within each sensor-gathering session? Is your DB properly configured?

Comment: Do you mean, not open database connections?

Comment: try to use a connection pool with a maximum number of parallel active connection. so the threads must wait untill a connection was released. of course this is just one piece of the whole solution

Comment: Show the code for your sensor sampling thread.

Comment: yes writing data to the database for every individual sensor and I think it is configured properly.

Comment: Did you try to remove parts of code to isolate the problem?  For example I would comment out the code inside the for(int i=0;i<instruments.size();i++) loop, and see how the system holds with this change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Reuse any open files or sockets whenever you can.  [DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) is a good start.
2. Reuse any threads if you can.  That *"comThread"* is very suspect in that regard.
3. Consider adding queues to your worker threads.  This will allow you to have threads that process tasks/jobs serially.
4. Profile, *Profile*, **Profile**!! You really have no idea what to optimize until you profile.  JProfiler and YourKit are both very popular, but there are some free tools such as Netbeans and [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/).
5. Use Database caching such as Redis or Memcache
6. Consider using Stored Procedures versus inline queries
7. Consider using a Service Oriented Architecture or Micro-Services.  Splitting each application function into a separate service which can be tightly optimized for that function.

These are from the smalll amount of code you posted.  But profile should give you a much better idea.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, I have started with DBCP, I have used Jet Profiler to profile Mysql database and I can see some queries are taking more time than others. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, glad it helped.  For MySQL, http://www.jetprofiler.com/ has been great for tracking slow queries, investigating Query Plans, etc.

Answer (score 2):

What you probably need is connection pooling - instead of opening one DB connection per sensor, have a shared pool of opened connections that each thread uses when it needs to access the DB. That way, the number of connections can be much smaller than the number of your sensors (assuming that most of the time, the program will do other things than read/write into the DB, like communicate with the sensor or wait for sensor response).

If you don't use a framework that has connection pooling feature, you can try [Apache Commons DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/).

Answer (score 1):

Databases are made to handle loads of way more than "hundreds of inserts" per minute. In fact a MySQL database can easily handle hundreds of inserts per second.So, you problem it's probably not related to the load.

The first goal it's to find out "What is slow" or "What is collapsing", run all the queries that your application runs and see if any of them are abnormally slow compared to the others. Alternatively configure the Slow Query Log (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html ) with parameters fitting to your problem, and then analice the output.

Once you find "What" is the problem, you can ask for help here with laying out more information. We have no way to help you with the information provided.

However, just as a hunch, what's the max_connections parameter value you have for your database? The default value it's 100 or 151 I think, so if you have more than 151 sensors connected at the database at the same time it will queue or drop the new incoming connections. If that's your issue you just have to minimise the time sensors are connected to your database and it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Collecting data from hundreds of sensors should not pose a performance problem if done correctly. To scale this process you should carefully manage your database connections as well as your sensor connections and you should leverage queues for the sensor-sampling and sensor-data writing processes. If your sensor count is stable, you can cache the sensor connection data, possibly with periodic updates to your sensor connection cache.

Use a connection pool to talk to your database. Query your database for the sensor connection information, then release that connection back to the pool as soon as possible -- do not keep the database connection open while talking to the sensor. It's likely reading sensor connection data (which talks to your database) can be done in a single thread, and that thread creates sensor sampling jobs for your executor.

Within each sensor sampling job, open the HTTP sensor connection, collect sensor data, close HTTP sensor connection, and then create a sensor data write job to write the sampling data to the database. Assuming your sensors are distinct nodes, an HTTP sensor connection pool is not likely to help much because HTTP client and server connections are relatively light (unlike database connections).

Writing sensor-sampling data back to the database should also be made in a queue and these database write jobs should use your database connection pool.

With this design, you should be able to easily handle hundreds of sensors and likely thousands of sensors with modest hardware running a Linux server OS as the collector and a properly configured database.

I suggest you test these processes independently, so you know the sustainable rates for each step:

1. reading and caching sensor connection data and create sampling jobs;
2. execute sampling jobs and create writing jobs; and,
3. execute sample data writing jobs.

Let me know if you'd like code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your system is (almost certainly) slowing down because of the enormous overhead of starting threads, opening database connections, and then closing them.   300 sensors means five of these operations per second, continuously.  That's too many.

Here's what you need to do to make this scalable.

**First step**

1. Make your sampling program long-running, rather than starting it over frequently.
2. Have it start a sensor thread for each 20 sensors (approximately).
3. Each thread will query its sensors one by one and insert the results into some sort of thread-safe data structure. A Bag or a Queue would be suitable.
4. When your sensor threads come to the end of each minute's work, make each of them sleep for the remaining time before the next minute starts, then start over.
5. Have your program start a single database-writing thread. That thread will open a database connection and hold it open. It will then take results from the queue and write them to the database, waiting when no results are available.
6. The database-writing thread should start a MySQL transaction, then INSERT some number of rows (ten to 100), then Commit the transaction and start another one, rather than using the default autocommit behavior. (If you're using MyISAM tables, you don't need to do this.)

This will drastically improve your throughput and reduce your MySQL overhead.

**Second step**

When your workload gets too big for a single program instance with multiple sensor threads to handle, run multiple instances of the program, each with its own list of sensors.

**Third step**

When the workload gets too big for a single machine, add another one and run new instances of your program on that new machine.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, I did not know about this. I thought it is best to start a thread and close it as soon as possible, now you are saying keep sampling program long running.

Comment: Right. I learned this the hard way; I was reading short data interchange messages (in HL7) from another system, and starting a thread to put each one into a DBMS. When I switched to a long running program with a pool of threads, my throughput went up by fifty times. It was amazing how badly the thread-per-item strategy performed.